# how to handle a nullpionter exception in java

Tags: java

I am facing a problem where I have a null pointer exception, I am trying to work on a video compression program, this is the part where the exception is appearing:

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    FileInputStream fis=null;
    File file=null;

    try
    {
        URL uri=CompressionTest.class.getResource("/Files/Video.mp4");

        file=new File(uri.getPath());

        fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    }
```

Comment: Check for nllptr before using the variables.

Comment: It would help if you were a bit more specific about the locus of the problem, such as by providing a stack trace.  From what you did provide, however, my best guess would be that `CompressionTest.class.getResource("/Files/Video.mp4")` is returning `null`, as it will do if no resource matching the given name is found.

Comment: If you read the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)), you'll notice that `getResource()` returns "A URL object or **null if no resource with this name is found**".  (emphasis mine)  This is most likely what is causing your NPE, but in the future please post a complete stack trace when asking for help with runtime errors.

Comment: Which line exactly is the exception appearing in? What does it say? Edit your question with the full stack trace and we'll be able to help you a lot better :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2):

Check whether the uri is null before using it:

```
if (uri===null) {
    //Handle the situation, propably throw other exception
}
//rest of the code
```

`Class.getResource` might return `null` if the resource is not available (as stated in its [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource-java.lang.String-))